# How to download a file that has url "rtmp" instead of "http"

Tags: google-chrome, internet, download

Can anyone help me as how to download the file that starts with url "rtmp".For e.g the link is >> rtmp://node1.weblivecasting.com:80/vod/*definst*//mp4:icai/IP4ACh7DeductionsFromGrossTotalIncomeP1.mp4

but this does not get downloaded.
Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

RTMP is an adobe protocol for sending encrypted streams of audio or video. This data can be downloaded with an application called RTMP Dump. But if the media is copyrighted be aware that decryping with RTMP dump is breaking the law.

[RTMP Dump](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/)